# Set multiple states in setState - React.js ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

How would I add the name const to the second setState method? In order to increment currentCompany I must include the prevState. When I attempt to add the name const it does not work.

```
const name = company.word;

this.setState({ name });

this.setState(prevState => ({
  currentCompany: (prevState.currentCompany + 1)
}));
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: why u r not clubbing these two in single setState ?

Answer (score 11):

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  name: company.word,
  currentCompany: (prevState.currentCompany + 1)
}));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write it like this also:

```
this.setState({ 
    name ,
    currentCompany: this.state.currentCompany + 1
})
```

Multiple `setState` within a function is not a good idea, try to do all the calculation then use `setState` once after that.

Comment: It's not a good idea to rely on this.state values when calculating the next state. - https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Is it possible to run the function and new name state in the same setState? Why is that not a good idea?

Comment: @ThomasMirmo because the state is actually updated in batches, not immediately after calling `setState`. What do you mean "Is it possible to run the function and new name state in the same setState" ... he just showed you, no?

Comment: I think he's saying shouldn't you use prevState? Something like ... `this.setState(prevState => ({ name, currentCompany: (prevState.currentCompany + 1) }));`

Answer (score -1):

Function onchange set multiple state
 onChange(field, value){

```
const next = {

 ...this.state,

[field]: value

 }
this.setState(next)

 }
```

on HTML use `onChange=e)=>this.onChange('title',e.target.value)}`